# Excel 2010: How to Run FUNCTION procedures in a cell on another range of cell change?

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I have Vba Function procedure with parameters in Module1 it works fine. I am calling it from cell which returns array(6) values updates 6 cells as a result

```
Cell AU3: =String_Evaluation(F3,J3,V3)
Cell AU4: =String_Evaluation(F4,J4,V4)
Cell AU5: =String_Evaluation(F5,J5,V5)
So on
```

Module1:

```
Option Explicit
Public CI_Max, CI_Min, CI_Avg, II_Max, II_Min, II_Avg, cellvalue As String
Public Tmp(6) As Variant

Function String_Evaluation(Input As String, output As String, rownumber As Range) As Variant

// Find Min Max and Average works fine
Tmp(0) = CI_Max
Tmp(1) = CI_Min
Tmp(2) = CI_Avg
Tmp(3) = II_Max
Tmp(4) = II_Min
Tmp(5) = II_Avg
String_Evaluation = Tmp

End Function
```

[image]

**Problem**:

Now I want to Automate: 
Any change in the cell W1:AT344 the Function in cell AU3 to AU5 has to re execute is it Possible? 
[image]

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("W1:AT344")) Is Nothing  Then

  Exit Sub

Else
  Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
  FirstRow = Target.Row
  LastRow = Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count - 1


  For FirstRow to LastRow
    Range(AU"& FirstRow, "AZ" & FirstRow).Value = String_Evaluation("F" & FirstRow,"J" & FirstRow,"V" & FirstRow)
    ...
    FirstRow = FirstRow + 1
  Next 

End If


End Sub
```

Try to understand what it's done here. It maybe won't run if you copy it one to one. But the method behind it should be clear. Everytime the worksheet changes, you have to check if one of the changed rows is in your data. Then update the changed row. Anyway i made another update to the code, try it again

Comment: As String_Evaluation(F3,J3,V3) returns array. I can't use the Cells(...).value

Comment: wait, so string_Evaluation Returns an Array, and you want to fill a cell with the value of the Array ?

Comment: so this could maybe work, but it should definitly be enough to Show you a way to solve it.

Comment: I am still facing error "run time error 424 object required" at line                                                                                          Range(Range("AU" & FirstRow).Row & ", " & Range("AZ" & FirstRow).Column).value = _
            String_Evaluation("F" & FirstRow, "J" & FirstRow, V & FirstRow)

Answer (score 1):

@Doktor OSwaldo: Thank u I updated my code.

Module 1:

I Updated Function parameter type from “String to Range”.

```
Function String_Evaluation(segmstr As Range, outputstr As Range, ByVal rownumber As Range) As Variant
........
End Function
```

In Worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
    If Intersect(Target, Range("W3:AT344")) Is Nothing Then

       Exit Sub

    Else

        LastRow = Range("AU344").Row

        For FirstRow = 3 To LastRow

          Range(Cells(FirstRow, 47), Cells(FirstRow, 52)) = _
          String_Evaluation(Range("F" & FirstRow), Range("J" & FirstRow), Range("V" & FirstRow))

        Next

    End If
End Sub
```